# Is it possible to see also the date of the package in the package list of TeX Live?

Tags: texlive

Recently I switched from MiKTeX (I'm working on Windows 10) to TeX Live.

All works well, the features are more or less the same, the TeX Live GUI is a little bit spartan but surely it isn't a problem.

However, there is a difference in the package list visualization, TeX Live shows the versions, which I find extremely useful, of course, while MiKTeX shows the date ("Packaged on"), which could be useful, too.

Is there a way to see also the date of the last update of the package in the package list of TeX Live?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tlmgr info` tells you everything that texlive knows about a package (or at least, everything it wants to tell you it knows)

for example

```
$ tlmgr info colortbl
package:     colortbl
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Add colour to LaTeX tables
longdesc:    The package allows rows and columns to be coloured, and even individual cells.
installed:   Yes
revision:    29803
sizes:       src: 49k, doc: 573k, run: 13k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.0a
cat-date:    2015-08-03 05:43:12 +0200
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  colour table
cat-related: xcolor
collection:  collection-latex
```

`cat-version`  is the package version as given in `\ProvidesPackage` `cat-date` is the date/time when some aspect of the cataloguing of the package was done. that's probably the date that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, exactly that date! Could I put also more than one package name after `tlmgr info` command?

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes just tried `tlmgr info colrtbl varwidth` and it seemed to do something:-)

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! With `colortbl`, of course...

Comment: Running `tlmgr info` on TL 2020 doesn't provide any dates. Has the `cat-date` been removed or has there been a change in how to obatin the information?

Comment: @Florian so it has, I have no idea, you could ask Karl and Norbert on the tex-live list, I guess.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you! (Sometimes I need to roll my installation back to a certain state, so dates are a huge help. Actually it would be awfully nice to be able to sort the package-list in the TeX Live Utility by date; but it looks like there aren't too many interested in package-dates)