# Understanding CTAN versions, release dates and announcements

Tags: ctan, versions

I am looking at https://ctan.org/pkg/sciposter where I see that the package version is 1.18 but the most recent announcement in the right sidebar is that of v1.17.

I am trying to understand how these things in CTAN work. Was it the case that a new release 1.18 was made but a corresponding announcement was not made and that's why this discrepancy exists?

If that's the case, how do I find out the release date of version 1.18?

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351007/101651

Comment: For the date, see above if you have TeX Live. If you have MiKTeX, it is listed in its package list.

Comment: You can normally find the date of the version you are using in the `.cls` (or `.sty`) files. Sometimes the documentation or the code itself has a more extensive change history with version numbers or dates, but that is not required (though I guess most packages have some kind of change history nowadays). The announcements are optional and some people choose not to announce minor changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CTAN do not impose any particular requirements on uploaders. In particular, there is no *requirement* for an announcement to go with an upload. Thus the latest announcement of a release and the latest release may be different: this is down to the package author.

The date you (probably) want is that given by the package author in their release, with will almost certainly match that picked up by LaTeX's `\@ifpackagelater`. This is typically given in the documentation, if the author uses a date at all.

Comment: There is also `tlmgr info ...`